# Slider moving in irregular steps

Tags: manipulate

Sorry - bit of a yes/no question: Is it possible to make the slider from a manipulation jump in irregular steps? Or would the best way to overcome this be to just create a series of buttons that jump the manipulation to the desired position?

Comment: Check the second argument of `Dynamic`

Comment: Great - will do that now :)

Comment: More specifically: [The Second Argument of Dynamic](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html#756925424)

Comment: If it doesn't matter where on the slider the knob lies, this syntax will do it: `Slider[Dynamic[x],{{val1,val2,val3,...}}]`. If it matters, look at the documentation page for `Slider`, last example under Scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just writing down what I and Rojo talked about in the comments, we get:

```
datapoints = {{1, 1}, {5, 4}, {20, 15}};
Manipulate[
 n,
 {n, datapoints, ControlType -> "Slider"},
 Initialization :> (n = 1)
 ]
```

where the slider jumps from 1 to 5 to 20. The gap between one and five is four, the gap between five and twenty is fifteen.