# Use the InteractiveTradingChart style slider in IntervalSlider

Tags: plotting, dynamic, user-interface

I want to combine IntervalSlider with a small plot,just like the InteractiveTradingChart.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InteractiveTradingChart.html

I can only find the closest example here:

[Dynamic PlotRange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137184/dynamic-plotrange)

but the IntervalSlider is still separated with the small plot. I also tried to find the source code of InteractiveTradingChartbut I can't find any.

Comment: There is an example under the Applications section in the IntervalSlider doc page, but it is currently broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I managed to make it by myself.

```
DynamicModule[{data, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, int, w = 400, h = 30}, 
 data = FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2004"];
 {ymin, ymax} = QuantityMagnitude@MinMax[data];
 {xmin, xmax} = {data["FirstTime"], data["LastTime"]};
 Column[{Show[DateListPlot[data, ImageSize -> w, Joined -> True], 
    PlotRange -> {Dynamic[int], {ymin, ymax}}],
   Row[{
     Spacer[10],
     Deploy[DateListPlot[data,
       Prolog -> {Opacity[0.4], EdgeForm[{Thick, GrayLevel[0.4]}], 
         LightBlue, 
         Dynamic[Rectangle @@ Thread[{int, {ymin - 5, ymax + 5}}]]},
       Epilog -> {Inset[
          IntervalSlider[Dynamic[int], {xmin, xmax, 1}, Appearance -> {
             "ThumbAppearance" -> {
               Graphics[{
                 AbsoluteThickness@5, GrayLevel[0.4], 
                 Line@{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}
                 }], None,
               Graphics[{
                 AbsoluteThickness@5, GrayLevel[0.4], 
                 Line@{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}
                 }]
               }, "BarAppearance" -> None
             }, ImageSize -> {400, 50}, Method -> "Stop", 
           MinIntervalSize -> 1], Scaled[{0.5, 0.6}]]},
       Frame -> False, Axes -> {True, False}, 
       PlotRange -> {ymin, ymax}, ImageSize -> {400, 50}, 
       AspectRatio -> 0.08, Joined -> True]
      ]
     }]
   }]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
When I apply this to my `Manipulate`, the coordinates in `Dynamic[Rectangle @@ Thread[{int, {ymin - 5, ymax + 5}}]]` need to be `Scaled`, otherwise nothing is displayed, I don't know why.

Also, my timeseries has irregular interval, I need to use `AbsoluteTime@DateObject[*data list*]` to make it function correctly.

Reference:
[Slider moving in irregular steps](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38801/slider-moving-in-irregular-steps)

[Make a time IntervalSlider](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78759/make-a-time-intervalslider)

EDIT2:
There is still a problem, which is the top and bottom edge of the rectangle in intervalslider is clipped. You may use

```
GrayLevel[0.6], Inset@
 Framed[" ", Background -> GrayLevel[0.8], 
  FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2], 
  FrameMargins -> {{0, 6}, {40, 40}}]
```

Comment: +1, great that you got it working :-) I just came back to take another look, and saw that you managed.